# How can I loop though each row in a text field?

Tags: php, trim

I have a textarea where I ask a user to type multiple values on a separate line. "One value per line"

Then I use the following function to loop though the values so I can insert them in the databases

```
function textToArrayEFL($text){

//explode all separate lines into an array
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);

//trim all lines contained in the array.
return array_filter($textAr, 'trim');
}
```

the problem with this function is that if the user wants to use the value "0" as a value it gets trimmed.

so if a user type the following

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

the first line gets eliminated but I want to keep it.

How can I fix this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map) instead of `array_filter`

`return array_map('trim', $textAr);`

**edit**: new code based on comment

```
function textToArrayEFL($text){
  $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
  return array_filter($textAr, function ($v) {
    return (trim($v)=='')?false:true;
  });
}
```

Comment: This causes a new issue. if the user enter a space or an extra return it will include the space as a valid option where it should not. I only want to use 0 as a valid option but not space/tab/ or return.   What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @Mike I updated my answer to handle that scenario. p.s. - taking away someone's solve/upvote for *your* failure to fully explain the situation is not cool. Esp so long after the fact. You shoulda started a new question.